SocketIO (python) make same iteration slower
I have a function called doCalibrate() which does iteration to move the stepper (GPIO Raspberry), let's say normally this function runtime is only 3 seconds.
This script was called from 2 source

executed from if __name__ == '__main__': which is when the script executed, here's the script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doCalibrate()


executed from socketio, here's the script

@sio.on(f'ms-calibrate')
def receive_calibrate(data):
    print(f"[SOCKET] Received calibrate")
    room_number = data['room_number']
    if (room_number == this_room_number):
        doCalibrate()

the first source runs the doCalibrate function for 3 seconds which is the actual time, but the second source runs the doCalibrate function for 5 seconds which is not the actual and optimal time.
Actually there is another function that make stepper move, but every action that comes from socket made the stepper move slower, but if the action come from let's said hardcode from the script or from call api every 1 minute and read index docalibrate is 1 the stepper speed is normal. Here's my stepper moving algorithm
for j in range(int(stepes)):
     GPIO.output(step_pin, 1)
     time.sleep(delays)
     GPIO.output(step_pin, 0)
     time.sleep(delays)

I expect the speed of stepper is same when the source is from socket or hardcode or from API, i have tried make 2 doCalibrate() function but speed still the same.

Are you using an async library here (gevent, eventlet)? Asynchronous code is more sensitive to concurrent tasks, if you are using one of these libraries I suggest you try using regular threads, which may provide better accurace for those sleep calls.

@MiguelGrinberg No I'm not, and yes I only use the regular threads package, I have tried call doCalibrate() inside a thread, but the speed is still slower than non-socket source

I can really tell from your description. Socket.IO doesn't really do much on its own, it just handles events from connected clients. There is nothing that can make Python run slower, so I assume the decrease in performance is due to the work that Socket.IO needs to do to respond to connected clients.
